# Laravel Session Destroy implementation

Tags: laravel

**Another newb queestion here**

How to apply session timeout in laravel? My app have this instance that when a user logs out. That previous route/s should not be loaded but my app loads it. how to implement in laravel that session destroy in PHP? Any ideas?

Comment: Here is a good resource. Pay attention to the version of Laravel you are using: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session. In Laravel 5.2, I think you have to group your routes in `web` middleware to apply all sessions automatically. Also, you may want to put your routes in the auth middleware so they are not available if user is not logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `routes/web.php` add your protected routes in a middleware group so they won't be accessible when logged out.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::get('profile', 'UserController@profile');
});
```

Then `/profile` will require users to be logged in. As well as any other routes in that group.

Learn more about sessions here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session

**Update**

I think I've got what you mean. After doing `Auth::logout();` do

```
return redirect()->back();
```

What will happen is the browser will try to redirect back to a 'protected' page and the protected page will kick them to the login page. WHen they click on 'back' on the browser, it will still display the login page.

Comment: Yes, I already tried that but still when i go back it still displays the previous page

Comment: Try what I did in my update. It works fine. after logout(), you redirect back(). it will prevent user from going back to the previous page. Read my answer again.

Comment: Yeah it worked. But what if i want to redirect to aspecific route